# Scheduled .bat file running SAS script fails to assign library but works when manually run?

Tags: batch-file, sas, scheduled-tasks

I have a scheduled task which is supposed to run a SAS script daily. It's unsuccessful, however, and leads to a result of `0x2`.

The `.bat` file is simply:

`"E:\Program Files\SAS\SASFoundation\9.2\Sas.exe" -sysin "C:\Documents and Settings\username\Desktop\myfolder\myscript.sas"`

I have logged the output and it indicates that the problem is that a library (and only 1 library of many) is not successfully being assigned:

```
2          libname COOLDB ORACLE user=Laureate pw=mypass path=COOLDB schema=ODSMGR;
NOTE: Libref COOLDB was successfully assigned as follows: 
      Engine:        ORACLE 
      Physical Name: COOLDB
3          %let prj = T:\DNA\New Orleans\username\SAS Export Folder;
4          libname dt "&prj.";
NOTE: Library DT does not exist.
```

where the first line is included just to demonstrate that it works up until that point.

This is strange to me because I know with 100% certainty that the folder/library being refrenced exists and has proper permissions.

When I run the same script manually there's no problem:

```
3    %let prj = T:\DNA\New Orleans\username\SAS Export Folder;
4    libname dt "&prj.";
NOTE: Libref DT was successfully assigned as follows:
      Engine:        V9
      Physical Name: T:\DNA\New Orleans\username\SAS Export Folder
```

Comment: Without seeing the full log it's hard to know for sure but I notice the path "SAS Export Folder" has spaces. I think the whitespace can be a problem depending on the system you're running on. How about if you use `%let prj=%str("T:\DNA\New Orleans\username\SAS Export Folder"); when submitting your .bat file?

Comment: @Bendy Good idea!! I will give that a try and report back. That's the one and only error message in the log.

Comment: @Bendy Hmmm this was the result:

`3          %let prj = %str("T:\DNA\New Orleans\username\SAS Export Folder");
4          libname dt "&prj.";
ERROR: Libref in LIBNAME statement must be followed either by quoted string or engine name or semicolon; """T" found.
ERROR: Error in the LIBNAME statement.`

Comment: You have too many quotation marks there.  You're adding them twice; either add them in the macro variable assignment OR in the libname assignment (the latter is usually preferred).

Comment: @Bendy Got it! I used your `%str()` command without any quotation marks and that worked! Thanks. If you want to post this as an answer I'll mark it as the solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on the server, some systems don't like the whitespace (as you have in `SAS Export Folder`) so you need to make sure the path in the libname statement is wrapped in quotes in these cases.

As Joe pointed out, don't double up on the quotes, so pass the path either as:

```
%let prj=%str(T:\DNA\New Orleans\username\SAS Export Folder);
libname dt "&prj.";
```

-or-

```
%let prj=%str("T:\DNA\New Orleans\username\SAS Export Folder");
libname dt &prj;
```